# is SetWindowRgn blocking?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, msdn, showwindow

I have an UI that can go to full screen.
When going to full screen I'm calling the sequence below:

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
SetWindowRgn(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, left, top, right, bottom, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER)) ;
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
```

I'm having a bug that the window first being displayed in the upper left corner with the previous size and only then goes to full screen size.
I suspect that this may be because`SetWindowRgn()` call is async. and actually being executed after `ShowWindow()`.
I know from documentation that all other calls are blocking, but, there is no comment about `SetWindowRgn()` whether it is blocking or not.
How can I be sure about it? Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you are observing a delay in painting of your window? When you resize it, windows moves existing bits to a new location and invalidates the newly added area. You could try to add SWP_NOCOPYBITS flag to your SetWindowPos() call. Or you could resize your window to an off-screen position, update it and move back in.

Answer (score 1):

> Is SetWindowRgn blocking?

Yes. This function, like all called in the code in the question, is synchronous.